# Return anonymous types from stored procedure

Tags: c#, types, procedure, anonymous

This question is just a duplicate of this question here:  [Returning anonymous types from stored procedure with LINQ2SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/603967/906449)

But its been 4 years and no one has answered it, so I was hoping I could like..bump it up. I really need this answered, been struggling with the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps use the dynamic data type?

Comment: See [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions), this is not the appropriate way to draw attention to an old unanswered question.

Comment: And what do you mean no one has answered it?  It's had an answer since the day it was asked, and that answer is 100% correct.  It can be done, but it's not particularly useful to do it.  Your best bet is to create a new type instead of using an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a xml-like string in your store procedure and then use XmlSerializer to deserialize it into a more complex object in runtime. Use an attribute in your xml so you can distinguish between different types of objects that your returning value is actually referring to.

EDIT:
One other workaround could be returning a varbinary object from your stored procedure which will include binary data needed to instantiate your desired object. Of course by using this method, it will be difficult to maintain your code.